# Grabbing the page template name?

Tags: page-template

I am attempting to compare a username to a page template name. I found the following code:

```
get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true );
```

But this isn't quite what I am looking for. This returns the filename of the page template, IE:

```
templates/page-products.php
```

What I am looking for is the actual template name defined in the page template here:

```
/*
Template Name: products
*/
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An alternative to @Ben Cole that's less intensive (especially if you have several page templates), but not as awesome because it doesn't use the `WP_Theme` object ;)

```
function wpse_184317_get_template_name( $page_id = null ) {
    if ( ! $template = get_page_template_slug( $page_id ) )
        return;
    if ( ! $file = locate_template( $template ) )
        return;

    $data = get_file_data(
        $file,
        array(
            'Name' => 'Template Name',
        )
    );

    return $data['Name'];
}
```

And in use:

```
echo wpse_184317_get_template_name(); // Template name for current page
echo wpse_184317_get_template_name( 14 ); // Template name for page ID 14
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to retrieve the name of the template as defined in the file could be like this:

```
function get_template_name () {
    // List all available template names for current theme
    $available_templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();

    // Get filename of page template we are on
    $template_filename = basename(get_page_template())

    // Return the template name for the currently active file
    return $available_templates[$template_filename];
}
```

The function above will return whatever text is used for the name of the template. In the example below, it would return "**NAME OF TEMPLATE**":

```
/*
Template Name: NAME OF TEMPLATE
*/
```

More info about the [WP_Theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Theme) object.

Comment: You don't want `basename`, it'll break for page templates in a sub-directory of the theme. Use `get_page_template_slug` and then an `isset` to check it's a valid index.